# How do I pass the environment of one R script to another?

Tags: r, command-line

I'm effectively trying to tack `save.image()` onto the end of a script without modifying that script.

I was hoping something like `Rscript target_script.R | saveR.R destination_path` would work, where `saveR.R` reads,

```
args.from.usr<-commandArgs(TRUE)
setwd(args.from.usr[1])
save.image(file=".RData")
```

But that clearly does not work. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an R script file that takes two parameters: 1, the script file you want to run, and 2, the file you want to save the image to.

```
# runAndSave.R ------
args.from.usr <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
source(args.from.usr[1])
setwd(args.from.usr[2])
save.image(file=".RData")
```

And then run it with

```
Rscript runAndSave.R target_script.R destination_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to program a task to be done within the OS of that computer. In Linux you will be using the terminal and there is this tool called CRON. In Windows you can use Task Scheduler. If you program the OS to open a terminal and load an script and later save the image, you maybe will get what you need, save the data generated from the script without actually modifying it.